# Why does scrolling stutter/shake on long Column and SingleChildScrollView flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

As I scroll up or down in flutter, the screen starts to shake/stutter.

Here is the video of what I am talking about (flutter run --release):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OdrmXNZAO78cOEjhGP6gd_mVKJ3Q_QIT/view?usp=sharing

I don't understand what is happening? Also, on other screens, there is jank/stuttering on ListView.builder:

I don't think the WebView is causing this problem since I have tried making a separate screen with only a WebView, and it does not lag and scrolls smoothly.

The code of the build method:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(242, 242, 242, 1),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: (imgUrl != '')
                        ? CachedNetworkImage(
                            imageUrl: imgUrl,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            fadeInDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                          )
                        : RepaintBoundary(
                            child: Shimmer.fromColors(
                              baseColor: Colors.black38,
                              highlightColor: Colors.white,
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.black12,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 13),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13),
                    child: (title != '')
                        ? AutoSizeText(
                            title,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 21.5,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                              color: Colors.black87,
                              letterSpacing: -0.5,
                            ),
                          )
                        : PlaceholderText(
                            numberOfItems: 2,
                            height: 21.0,
                          ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 13),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13),
                    child: const GrayLine(),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 9),
                  (author != '')
                      ? Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              const Text(
                                'AUTOR: ',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Colors.black87,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                author,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      : const SizedBox(),
                  (author != '') ? const SizedBox(height: 4) : const SizedBox(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13),
                    child: (date != '')
                        ? Text(
                            date,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          )
                        : PlaceholderText(
                            numberOfItems: 1,
                            height: 17.0,
                            endWidth: 200.0,
                          ),
                  ),
                  (articleUrl != '') ? const SizedBox(height: 7) : const SizedBox(),
                  (articleUrl != '')
                      ? Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                shares,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 3),
                              const Icon(
                                Icons.share,
                                size: 18,
                                color: Colors.black54,
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 7),
                              ShareIconsBar(articleUrl: articleUrl),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      : const SizedBox(),
                  const SizedBox(height: 9),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13),
                    child: const GrayLine(),
                  ),
                  (introduction != '')
                      ? SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        )
                      : SizedBox(),
                  (introduction != '')
                      ? Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13.0),
                          child: Text(
                            introduction,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17.5,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              letterSpacing: -0.5,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : const SizedBox(),
                  (_isAdLoaded) ? SizedBox(height: 13) : SizedBox(),
                  (_isAdLoaded) ? Center(child: bannerAdWidget()) : SizedBox(),
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      (isViewVisible)
                          ? SizedBox(
                              height: contentHeight.toDouble(),
                              child: RepaintBoundary(
                                child: InAppWebView(
                                  onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) async {
                                  
                                  },
                                  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                                    crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                                      supportZoom: false,
                                      cacheEnabled: false,
                                      useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
                                      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
                                    ),
                                    android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
                                      useHybridComposition: true,
                                    ),
                                    // ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
                                    //   suppressesIncrementalRendering: true,
                                    // ),
                                  ),
                                  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                                    _webViewController = controller;
                                    loadLocalHTML();
                                  },
                                  onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, url) {
                                    print('Loading Started');
                                  },
                                  onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, url) async {
                                    print('Loading Stopped');
                                    _isLoaded = true;
                                  },
                                  onProgressChanged: (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                                    print(progress);
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          : const SizedBox(),
                      (!_isLoaded)
                          ? Container(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              height: 100,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: const Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13.0),
                                child: PlaceholderText(
                                  numberOfItems: 4,
                                  height: 17.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          : const SizedBox()
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            (relatedArticlesFinal.isNotEmpty)
                ? (relatedArticlesFinal.length >= 2)
                    ? IzdvojenoSection(
                        izdvojenoNews: relatedArticlesFinal,
                        title: 'vezani tekstovi',
                      )
                    : const SizedBox()
                : const SizedBox(),
            (categogryArticlesFinal.isNotEmpty)
                ? (categogryArticlesFinal.length >= 1)
                    ? MoreFromCategory(news: categogryArticlesFinal)
                    : const SizedBox()
                : const SizedBox(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      //   ],
      // ),
    );
  }

  Widget bannerAdWidget() {
    return RepaintBoundary(
      child: StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) => Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd),
          width: _bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
          height: _bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Flutter version:

```
Flutter 2.12.0-4.2.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5c931b769b (2 weeks ago) • 2022-03-29 10:49:29 -0500
Engine • revision 486f4a749e
Tools • Dart 2.17.0 (build 2.17.0-182.2.beta) • DevTools 2.11.
```

I have tried running it on master branch, but it is even worse there!

Thank You!